# calling Python cgi fieldstorage multiple times

Tags: python, cgi

I'm not too familiar with cgi.FieldStorage() for python and I'm running into trouble in my project. Basically, on my main page, I have a html form named criterion. The form's action calls process.py which uses FieldStorage() to get the input from the form and generate a new result page. It loads fine for the first time.

```
 <form action="process.py" name="SearchForm">
 <select id="criterion">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="result1">Result 1</option>
        <option value="result2">Result 2</option>
    </select>
 <input type = "submit">
 </form>
```

My problem is that in my process.py, I use Python to generate the same html as the main page. So the result page also have a form called criterion that calls process.py. However, if I input something in the form again, process.py is called but cgi.FieldStorage is completely empty. Is it possible to fix that?

Edit: In my process.py

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
if 'criterion' in form:
table_name = form['criterion'].value


print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
print """\
  <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>  
  <form action="process.py" name="SearchForm">
    <select id="criterion">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="result1">Result 1</option>
        <option value="result2">Result 2</option>
    </select>
 <input type = "submit">
 </form>"""
 select(table_name)
```

print """\
"""

This is not all my code, but this is gist of it. select(table_name) is the python method use to generate the info depending on the value of criterion. Once again, process.py is being called but cgi.fieldstorage() is empty now.

Comment: Can you show us your python code?

Comment: hi there, I added some code in my edit.

Comment: By the way, is there any reason why you don't you any framework (such as bottle or web.py) that makes you things easier?

Comment: I not really familiar with all these frameworks. I just found an example online and I used it.

Comment: I'm telling you that because I'm not familiar with cgi, I've always used one of those frameworks, it worth spending a couple of days understanding them, it will save you a lot of time and you will be much moooooore productive. I strongly recommend you to give http://bottlepy.org/ a chance

Comment: I would...except my project is due in a few hours....but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cgi.FieldStorage()` consumes standard input, so it should be instantiated only once. Are you sure that you don't instantiate it another time under any conditions? Recommended solution to that problem is placing the first instance in a variable and passing it as argument to functions which need access to request data.

Also, you might try putting full `process.py` url (i.e. `http://localhost/process.py`) in form action and see if that helps.

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

Comment: I think I'm instantiating cgi.FieldStorage() more than once and that's why it's returning empty

Comment: So maybe you should keep the first instance in some form variable and pass it on to functions that need access to request data?

Comment: what about changing the fields? for example, criterion is originally result1 so it generates the result page for result1. Then on the result page for result1 I call process.py again with result2.

Comment: you may instantiate it only once per request, that means it should work properly after sending the form again. You could try enabling cgitb (`import cgitb
cgitb.enable()`) and see debug output in case of any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the code is giving you an exception, so you can always use try/except. This is not the best way to do it, but i guess it might work.

```
flag = True
try:
    form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
    if 'criterion' in form:
        table_name = form['criterion'].value
exception:
    # you catch the exception
    flag = False
```

Now with flag you can control the situation in which you have FieldStorage empty:

```
if flag:
    select(table_name)  
else:
    # do whatever
    pass
```